# map on react returns empty div

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

i'm using map to loop trough an array and then fill a div with it, but it's always empty:

Here's some of my code:

```
const [scoreOptions, setScoreOptions] = useState(initialScoreOption);
const initialScoreOption = [
        { id: 1, selected: false, icon: 'far fa-smile', label: 'lala'},
        { id: 2, selected: false, icon: 'far fa-meh', label: 'lalala'},
        { id: 3, selected: false, icon: 'far fa-frown', label: 'lalala'}
    ];
let iconosTexto;
if (scoreOptions){
    iconosTexto = scoreOptions.map(icono => {
        return(
            <div className="contenedorIconoTexto">
                <div className="iconoElemento">
                    <i className={blue ? `blueIcon ${icono.icon}` : `greyIcon ${icono.icon}`}>
                    </i>
                </div>
                <div className="iconoTexto">
                    {icono.label}
                </div>
            </div>
        )       
    });
}
```

and then i have this on the render

```
<div className="container">
    { iconosTexto }
</div>
```

The div with the class container it's empty when it should be filled with all of the above
Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, declare `initialScoreOption` before `useState(initialScoreOption)`.

Use set `key` prop while rendering elements in map:

```
iconosTexto = scoreOptions.map((icono) => {
  return (
    <div key={icono.id} className="contenedorIconoTexto">
     ...
```

Then make sure that `iconosTexto` has always value.

Comment: I did that, added the key also, but i'm getting the "too many re renders" error

Comment: @antonellamanzur I might be because you calling `setScoreOptions` (or other state updater functions) somewhere inside the component in every render.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way :

```
const IconosTexto = () => scoreOptions.map(icono => {
    return (
        <div className="contenedorIconoTexto">
            <div className="iconoElemento">
                <i className={blue ? `blueIcon ${icono.icon}` : `greyIcon ${icono.icon}`}
                    >
                </i>
            </div>
            <div className="iconoTexto">{icono.label}</div>
        </div>
    )
}

render (
    <div className="container">
        <IconosTexto />
    </div>
)
```

Comment: I tried but i get this " <iconosTexto /> is using incorrect casing."

Comment: it's IconosTexto with a capital I , not i. Check again my example :), also you need to use the arrow function to create it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare `initialScoreOption` **before** passing it to `useState`:

```
const initialScoreOption = [
    { id: 1, selected: false, icon: 'far fa-smile', label: 'lala'},
    { id: 2, selected: false, icon: 'far fa-meh', label: 'lalala'},
    { id: 3, selected: false, icon: 'far fa-frown', label: 'lalala'}
];
const [scoreOptions, setScoreOptions] = useState(initialScoreOption);
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/divine-worker-txvgz?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, i did that and now i'm getting this error "Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop."

Comment: You need to add a `key` to your `divs` inside `.map` ( I added a demo link to my answer)